# Having difficulty splitting a tibble using group_split

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a function that computes values but before executing the function I need to split the df.  The Dput is as follows:

```
  structure(list(ID = c("35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", 
  "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", 
  "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", 
  "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", 
  "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", 
  "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", "35124-54739-2024-02-24", 
  "35124-54739-2024-02-24"), Book = c("bet365", "bet365", "bet365", 
  "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", 
  "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", "bet365", 
  "bet365"), Home = c("Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", 
  "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", 
  "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", 
  "Kentucky", "Kentucky"), Away = c("Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
  "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
  "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
  "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"), Team = c("Alabama", "Alabama", 
  "Kentucky", "Kentucky", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Kentucky", "Kentucky", 
  "Alabama", "Kentucky", "Alabama", "Kentucky", "Alabama", "Kentucky", 
  "Alabama", "Kentucky", "Alabama", "Kentucky"), Price = c(110L, 
  130L, -175L, -150L, 100L, 140L, -190L, -140L, -105L, -130L, -110L, 
  -110L, -130L, -105L, -135L, 100L, -140L, 105L), Points = c(1, 
  -1, 1, -1, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 2, -2, 2.5, -2.5, 3, -3, 3.5, 
  -3.5, 4, -4)), row.names = c(NA, -18L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame"))
```

This is the command that I am using to attempt splitting along with the output.

```
  ncaab_spread_all %>% 
    group_split(ID, Book, abs(Points))

  [[1]]
  # A tibble: 4 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    110      
  1             1
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    130     
  -1             1
  3 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -175      
  1             1
  4 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -150     
  -1             1

  [[2]]
  # A tibble: 4 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    100    
  1.5           1.5
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    140   
  -1.5           1.5
  3 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -190    
  1.5           1.5
  4 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -140   
  -1.5           1.5

  [[3]]
  # A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -105      
  2             2
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -130     
  -2             2

  [[4]]
  # A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -110    
  2.5           2.5
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -110   
  -2.5           2.5

  [[5]]
  # A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -130      
  3             3
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -105     
  -3             3

  [[6]]
  # A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -135    
  3.5           3.5
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky   100   
  -3.5           3.5

  [[7]]
  # A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -140      
  4             4
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky   105     
  -4             4
```

Tibbles 3 - 7 split properly and are correctly formatted for my function.  They contain 2 rows.  The Team column should contain each Team and the Points column should contain the corresponding Points value.  The problem with Tibble 1 and 2 is that my group_split didn't properly split them and I think it's because in the original Dput each of the Teams have multiple Points values.  In Tibble 1 each Team has a 1 and -1 Points value.  In Tibble 2 each Team has a 1.5 and -1.5 Points value.  For Tibbles 3 - 7 each Team has a single value.

My goal is to have all Tibbles formatted like 3 - 7.  So Tibble 1 and 2 should actually be split further and should look like this.

```
  [[1]]
  # A tibble: 4 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    110      
  1             1
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -150     
  -1             1

  [[2]]
  # A tibble: 4 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   130      
  1             1
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -150     
  -1             1


  [[3]]
  # A tibble: 4 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  
  <dbl>         <dbl>
  1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    100    
  1.5           1.5
  2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky   -140   
  -1.5           1.5

  [[4]]
  # A tibble: 4 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price 
  Points `abs(Points)`
  3 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama  140    
  -1.5           1.5
  4 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -190   
  1.5           1.5
```

Tibbles 3 - 7 from the original group_split would then become Tibbles 5 - 9.  I added the abs(Points) column while trying to split the data but if there is a better way then it can be omitted.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to interpret your original data and how we would know which data should be used for the output (and in what grouping) and which rows should be disregarded. It looks here like the first 4 columns are all identical but you want to use Team, Price, and Points to determine the output. By what observation would we know the four rows in your output (based on three of the input rows) are the ones that matter out of the 18 provided? Why row 1+4 in one tibble and row 2+4 in the other?

Comment: @JonSpring I've updated my original post.  Let me know if it makes more sense and if not I will edit it further.

Comment: @AaronMorris for the first example now, you're using rows 1 and 4, then 2 and 4 (i.e. you use 4 twice). The second example, it's 1 and 4, 2 and 3.

Comment: I'm voting to close because, despite your edits, it's still completely opaque what your rules are. It's unclear if the rules are clear, even to yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach where we presume that each game has unique pairs of observations where the Points of the Home and Away teams match except in sign. (If there could be multiple observations in a game where the same team had the same Points, it's not clear to me how we could know how they should pair up with observations from the other team.)

```
ncaab_spread_all |>
  mutate(Points_Home = Points * if_else(Team == Home, 1, -1)) |>
  group_split(ID, Book, Home, Away, Points_Home)
```

Result

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -140      4          -4
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky   105     -4          -4

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -135    3.5        -3.5
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky   100   -3.5        -3.5

[[3]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -130      3          -3
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -105     -3          -3

[[4]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -110    2.5        -2.5
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -110   -2.5        -2.5

[[5]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama   -105      2          -2
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -130     -2          -2

[[6]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    100    1.5        -1.5
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -140   -1.5        -1.5

[[7]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    110      1          -1
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -150     -1          -1

[[8]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    130     -1           1
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -175      1           1

[[9]]
# A tibble: 2 × 8
  ID                     Book   Home     Away    Team     Price Points Points_Home
  <chr>                  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>   <chr>    <int>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Alabama    140   -1.5         1.5
2 35124-54739-2024-02-24 bet365 Kentucky Alabama Kentucky  -190    1.5         1.5
```

Comment: JonSpring, I appreciate your efforts!  With a gambling line there is always a Points value and it's opposite value assigned.  Based upon your results, if you look at Tibbles 1-4 you will notice the Points values are the same for each Team.  Tibbles 5-9 you will notice that the Points values are opposite.  Tibbles 5-9 are the format that I am looking for.   I may need to take a different approach and not use group_split.

Comment: What if there are multiple observations in one game where the Points are the same? How would we know which rows should be paired?

Comment: Please see edit. I am presuming that the ambiguity above does not exist in the data. If it does, please clarify how it should be resolved.

Comment: Jon Spring, my friend you are a genius, this is what I was after!  Regarding your question about ambiguity, it's not really ambiguity but rather a single game offers multiple lines for the same Teams which is extremely common.

Game line #1 - Alabama 1/Kentucky -1, Game line #2 - Alabama -1/Kentucky 1.  

I think everyone will learn something from this post, including how to be PATIENT with others!